# Using Watir on WSL2 - Selenium Webdriver error

Tags: ruby

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 via WSL2. Trying to use Watir to do some scraping.

This command:

a = Watir::Browser.new

results in this error:

```
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:319:in `create_bridge': unknown keyword: :desired_capabilities (ArgumentError)

        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:74:in `initialize'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `new'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `for'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/watir-6.19.1/lib/watir/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from (irb):5:in `new'
        from (irb):5:in `<main>'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/irb-1.6.2/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/bin/irb:25:in `load'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/bin/irb:25:in `<main>'
```

I have installed chromedriver in /usr/bin.

Any starting point with fixing this error is appreciated.

Comment: What is your Watir version? You need Watir 7 to work with Selenium 4. Please upgrade to Watir 7 or later version of Watir if you don't have Watir >= 7 installed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by update Watir.